How to avoid particular cells which are having conditional formatting in the Spreadsheet?
I have prepared a spreadsheet with conditional formatting and following are the details.
Cell=K39 is having Data Validation clause.
Excel cell with Data Validation Clause
when the K39>= 3, particular cell range is visible to edit the data and if the value is less than 3, this cell range would not appear.
The particular cell range is not visible with K39=2
The particular cell range is visible with K39=3
However, I am having different colour coding for excel for appearance and the sheet is printing in 'Black and White'
Sheet is printing in Black and White
The query is, upon seeing the excel if K39=2 the conditionally formatted data is not visible. however, while printing the data is getting printed. So, how to control the printing the conditionally formatted cells when my K39 value is 1 or 2.
the excel sheet structure will be protected from editing to the users. So, instead of deleting the rows/columns, I am looking for another solution.

There are several possible ways e.g.: using the custom format code ;;; hiding cell content (you can use it in conditional formatting), defining limited print area, hiding the rows you don't want to print.

Or you can simple print in grayscale instead of black and white.

when I am using ;;; for the cell format, the cell content is not visible in all conditions. But I want to print the data when the K39>=3.
